# The method readerFor(Class) is undefined for the type CsvMapper

Tags: java, eclipse, jackson, dependencies, csvtojson

#### The source code:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;    
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;    
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;

public class ConvertCSVtoJson {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File input = new File("C:\\Users\\prshanka\\Documents\\Report.csv");
        CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.builder().setUseHeader(true).build();
        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();

        // Read data from CSV file
        List<Object> readAll = (csvMapper).readerFor(Map.class).with(csvSchema).readValues(input).readAll();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        // Write JSON formated data to output.json file
        for (Object row : readAll) {
            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) row;
            String fileName = map.get("fileName");
            File output = new File("C://Users//prshanka//Documents//Target" + fileName + ".txt");
            mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(output, row);
        }
    }
}
```

#### The line in which I am getting an error:

```java
List<Object> readAll = (csvMapper).readerFor(Map.class).with(csvSchema).readValues(input).readAll();
```

#### The error log:

```
Error- The method readerFor(Class<Map>) is undefined for the type CsvMapper.
```

I have added all the dependencies on the build path but it's still not working.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What version of the Jackson libraries are you using?

Comment: I am using all the latest versions. It's 2.9.5

Comment: 2.9.5 is nowhere near the latest version. These are: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson#active-developed-jackson-2x-branches. Regardless, I still can't reproduce.

Comment: i have tried it with 2.12 versions also . But  didnt work.

Comment: Are you using a recent version of `CsvMapper` but an older version of `JacksonMapper`?

Comment: No all are of same versions

Comment: @Sotirios Now while running program i am getting error- " Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xb4 (at char #925, byte #923): check content encoding, does not look like UTF-8". Could you please suggest?